# Is there any possibility that this class may be unsafe?

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I've made this class to read binary files and store their data.

FileInput.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class FileInput
{
public:
    FileInput(LPSTR Filename);
    FileInput(LPWSTR Filename);
    ~FileInput();
    operator char*();
    explicit operator bool();
    size_t Size;
private:
    __forceinline void Read();
    ifstream File;
    char* Data;
};
```

FileInput.cpp

```
#include "FileInput.h"

FileInput::FileInput(LPSTR Filename)
{
    File.open(Filename, ios::binary);
    Read();
}


FileInput::FileInput(LPWSTR Filename)
{
    File.open(Filename, ios::binary);
    Read();
}


FileInput::~FileInput()
{
    if (Data) delete[] Data;
}


FileInput::operator char*()
{
    return Data;
}


FileInput::operator bool()
{
    return (bool)Data;
}


void FileInput::Read()
{
    if (!File)
    {
        Data = nullptr, Size = 0;
        return;
    }
    File.seekg(0, ios::end);
    Size = (size_t)File.tellg();
    File.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    Data = new char[Size];
    File.read(Data, Size);
    File.close();
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
FileInput File(Filename);    // This reads the file and allocates memory

if (!File)    // This is for error checking
{
    // Do something
}

if (File.Size >= sizeof(SomeType))
{
    char FirstChar = File[0];    // Gets a single character
    SomeStruct *pSomeStruct = reinterpret_cast<SomeStruct*>(&File[0]);    // Gets a structure
}
```

So, is there any possibility that this class may be unsafe?

A `reinterpret_cast<SomeStruct*>(&File)` or other nonsense statement doesn't count.

EDIT: What I mean with unsafe is "to do unexpected or 'dangerous' things".

Comment: If you want a code review, you might want to ask on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For example, your class is copyable, but copying an instance will lead to double deletion.

Comment: @dyp Thanks. So how can I make my class "not copyable" (because it's not supposed to allow that).

Comment: This code is very bad and I would not use it. Use standard data structures. And if you don't want us to count your dangerous casts, why did you include that code at all?

Comment: @NeilKirk There is a big difference between `reinterpret_cast<SomeStruct*>(&File)` (wrong) and `reinterpret_cast<SomeStruct*>(&File[0])` (right). What I meant was not count the first one because it would be dumb.

Comment: Write-access to all data. Doesn't take charge of copying. Using compiler-specific extensions. Conversion to boolean not const. Using `char` as byte type instead of `unsigned char`. Needlessly using Windows API. `using namespace std;` in global scope in header file. Member variable never used after construction.

Comment: Both are wrong. You can't load binary data from a file, read it as a struct pointer and expect it to work. At least not in standard C++.

Comment: To keep your class from being copyable, declare the copy constructor and the assignment operator as private. You do not have to define them because you actually do not want anyone using them.  It should be impossible for any class outside your class to copy it once you declare them private, but by not defining them, you ensure that you don't make a mistake in your class by accidentally calling the copy constructor or assignment operator within a class member.

Answer (score 0):

This is major overkill. If you want to copy a file into a buffer, you can use use an `istreambuf_iterator`:

```
std::ifstream inFile(fileName);
std::vector<char> fileBuffer ( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile)),
                                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );
```

Then you can read from `fileBuffer` as necessary.

Comment: You might want to check the efficiency of that. There are many problems with the code but reading the file in one operation isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm googling `istreambuf_iterator` right now.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf He could `reserve` in advance if he discovers reallocations take too much time. Though it also also possible performing the extra hard drive seeks would be even more costly.

Comment: Okay, got it. If I reserve in advance, is there any difference `vector` and `string` in this case? (I would prefer to use `vector` only when it changes size).